# there is no message or log in console when executing the command discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I come with a problem that I can't solve despite several attempts, and when I enter the .balance or .work command, there is no message and error log in the console.

main.py:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from webserver import keep_alive
import json
import os

os.chdir("/home/runner/exidexi")

intents = discord.Intents.all()

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".", intents=intents, case_insensitive=True)
client.remove_command('help')


@client.event
async def on_ready():
  await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game('.pomoc'))
  print("Bot is currently online!")

@client.event
async def setup_hook():
  for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
    if filename.endswith('.py'):
      await client.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')
      print(f"Loaded Cog: {filename[:-3]}")
    else:
      print("Unable to load pycache folder.")

keep_alive()
token = os.environ.get("discord_bot_secret")
client.run(token)
```

economy.py:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import datetime
import random
import json
import os

class balance(commands.Cog):

  def __init__(self, client):
    self.client = client

  @commands.Cog.listener()
  async def on_ready(self):
      print("economy.py is ready!")

  @commands.command()
  async def balance(self, ctx):
      await open_account(ctx.author)
    
      users = await get_bank_data()
      user = ctx.author

      wallet_amt = users[str(user.id)]["wallet"]
      bank_amt = users[str(user.id)]["bank"]

      embed = discord.Embed(title = f"{ctx.author.name}'s balance",color = discord.Color.red())
      embed.add_field(name = "Wallet balance",value = wallet_amt)
      embed.add_field(name = "Bank balance",value = bank_amt)
      await ctx.reply(embed = embed)

  @commands.command()
  async def work(self, ctx):
      await open_account(ctx.author)
     
      users = await get_bank_data()
      user = ctx.author
    
      earnings = random.randrange(101)
      await ctx.reply(f"Someone gave you {earnings} coins!!")
    
      users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] += earnings

      with open("mainbank.json","w") as f:
          json.dump(users,f)

  async def open_account(user):

      users = await get_bank_data()
      user = ctx.author

      if str(user.id) in users:
          return False
      else:
          users[str(user.id)] = {}
          users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] = 0
          users[str(user.id)]["bank"] = 0

      with open("mainbank.json","w") as f:
          json.dump(users,f)
      return True

  
  async def get_bank_data():
      with open("mainbank.json","r") as f:
          users = json.load(f)

      return users

async def setup(client):
  await client.add_cog(economy(client))
```

in mainbank.json:

```
{

}
```

I saw similar questions, but there was at least one error, but i dont have at least one. However, I tried to do as written, but nothing helped. I also tried removing await and async with open_account and get_bank_data but it didnt help.

Comment: You don't print or log anything to the console when those commands are run.
What is the intended output you wanted to console?

Comment: I thought that when the commands don't work, maybe some error will be displayed in the console. What should I do?

Comment: Add a print in your commands to check if they're run, add a `cog_load` with a print to check that the cog is loaded

Comment: I added what you said to cog, when I started bot it normally showed a log in console with message that was to be printed

Comment: Oh, i moved it from cogs to main.py with some small changes and now it works